# Using aws profiles in python2 boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ec2

I'd like my python script (connecting to aws) to use aws profiles from ~/.aws/credentials

So, I have ~/.aws/credentials file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = AAA
region = eu-west-1

[test]
aws_access_key_id = WWW
aws_secret_access_key = ZZZ
region = eu-west-1
```

My python code

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.EC2Connection(profile_name='test')
print conn
print conn.get_all_instances()
```

The output is

```
EC2Connection:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[]
```

So, it doesn't seem to take the profile from the config. The region is wrong.

```
env | grep -i aws <- returns nothing
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

===== UPDATE =====

I have a ~/.aws/config file too which looks like

```
⟩ cat config
[default]
output = text
region = eu-west-1

[profile test]
output = text
region = eu-west-1
```

===== UPDATE =====

apparently, it takes connection details.. but not region. So, if I do

```
reg = next(x for x in boto.ec2.regions() if x.name=='eu-west-1')

conn = boto.ec2.EC2Connection(profile_name='test', region=reg)
print conn
print conn.get_all_instances()
```

I can get a list of the instances.

So, the problem is how to get the default 'region' from AWS config/credentials.

Comment: I've noticed the same issue. I'm curious if a solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

The `credentials` file is supposed to be used only for credentials.  If you want to supply other attributes for your profiles you should do that in the `~/.aws/config` file.  So, in your case you would create a config file containing:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1

[test]
region = eu-west-1
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the config file already, which defines the region. Updated the question with it.